# Best way to loop through thousands of files in one directory

Tags: php, filesystems, odbc

I have up to 40 000 images stored in one directory (ID photos).  I need to periodically synchronize them with a database.  I'm currently using a PHP script to loop through the directory and add new files and remove missing files, through ODBC.  Obviously, this is not working so well.

Is there a robust way to it in PHP?  Or, what is the best alternative?

Thanks

Comment: cron jobs, process 100 files one time

Comment: File synchronization and a database... You really need to give us more information about what you are trying to accomplish, if we are to give you a good answer. Also, knowing why your current solution is not working would also help. Programs like `rsync` and `cron` come to mind.

Comment: I'm trying to keep a database of ID photos, and their locations & file names, updated.  All the ID photos are and will be stored in one directory.  PHP times out after about 1700 files if I simply use readdir().

Comment: Then as @DmytroZarezenko mentioned. cron job and only a few at a time. A more complex alternative is to build a web page that handles 100 at a time and displays a nice progress bar :-)